# How to do [HttpGet] from ASP.NET core for arbitrary argument

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I learn Angular with APS.NET core and the CRUD principle

I have this two methods like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve all items from Books.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Books items List</returns>
// GET: api/BooksXml
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBookItems()
{
    List<BookItem> BookItems = new List<BookItem>();
    XDocument doc = _db.GetXmlDb();
    List<BookItem> bookitems = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookItem()
    {
        Id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
        Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
        Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
        Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
        Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
        Publish_date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
        Description = (string)x.Element("description")
    }).ToList();
    return Ok(bookitems);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a Book item matching the given id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Id of item to be retrieved</param>
/// <returns>Book item</returns>
// GET: api/BooksXml/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetBookItems(string id)
{
    XDocument doc = _db.GetXmlDb();
    XElement result = doc.Descendants("book").FirstOrDefault(el => el.Attribute("id") != null &&
                 el.Attribute("id").Value == id);
    List<BookItem> BookItems = new List<BookItem>();
    if (result != null)
    {
        BookItem Book = new BookItem();
        Book.Id = (string)result.Attribute("id");
        Book.Author = (string)result.Element("author");
        Book.Title = (string)result.Element("title");
        Book.Genre = (string)result.Element("genre");
        Book.Price = (decimal)result.Element("price");
        Book.Publish_date = (DateTime)result.Element("publish_date");
        Book.Description = (string)result.Element("description");
        BookItems.Add(Book);

    }
    return Ok(BookItems);
}
```

They are both get methods right, what I wanted more was to have another get with a route so I could search my backend books databas for the book title.

like this: (BooksXmlController.cs)

```
 /** GET all books from server. */
  getBookItems(): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(this.BookItemsUrl);
  }

  /** GET book by id. */
  getBookItem(id: string): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(url);
  }

  /** GET book by title from server. */
  getBookByTitle(title: string): Observable<BookItem> {
    const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}/${title}`;
    return this.http.get<BookItem>(url);
  }
```

Notice the `getBookByTitle` , how do I map the "title" to the ASP.NET core backend [HttpGet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another action in your controller which accepts a string as parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBookItemsByTitle(string title)
{
}
```

If you want to call this action, url will be:

```
 const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}?title=${title}`;
```

I suggest to take a look over [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing).

EDIT:

If you want to reuse your currently existent code, remove the `{id}` from the route and add the title:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBookItems(string id, string title)
{
}
```

After that, you can call your method using those URLs:

```
const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}?id=${id}`;
const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}?title=${title}`;
const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}?id=${id}&title=${title}`;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a method in the controller with a string like GetBookItems(string id), I understand I dont understand but I learn...:)

Comment: Do you want to re-use the method GetBookingItems(string id) method?

Comment: I want to have a search for Book tittle, author, price and more maybe it´s not a good idea to use one method for that

Comment: It feels more like a need for a "SearchBookItems". In the first comment you said that you already have a method in the controller accepting a string as parameter. It is not wrong to have multiple methods that are accepting the same kind of parameters if they have a different kind of logic (Search/Get)

Comment: When I try this my controller method does not work, I create GetBookItemsByTitle(string title), and I even decorate it with or without the "title"like - [HttpGet("{title}")], I read in log : Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44378/api/BooksXml?title=aaaaa  Route matched with {action = "GetBookItems", controller = "BooksXml", page = ""}. Any ide?

Comment: Can you provide us your latest version of the code?

Comment: Thanks I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652873/whats-wrong-with-my-asp-net-core-crud-call-when-wrong-method-match) a new question on this

Comment: In my answer I didn't have [HttpGet("{title}")] but [HttpGet]. Did you try to use the code posted by me?

Comment: I try this that and get - Route matched with {action = "GetBookItems", controller = "BooksXml", page = ""}

Comment: It works when I do: [HttpGet("title/{title}")] and const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}/title/${title}`;

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by define route constrain like

int constrain so your route will only accept int id

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult GetBookItems(int id)
```

alpha stands (Accepts only alphabets)

```
[HttpGet("{title:alpha}")]
public GetBookByTitle(string title)
```