# Whats wrong with my ASP.NET Core Crud call when wrong method match

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio

I have this three methods in my Angular ASP.NET core Controller but the last one does not fire, the others works ok, it´s the `GetBookItemsByTitle`. Since I´m learning this my mistake here is probably obvious..

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve all items from Books.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Books items List</returns>
// GET: api/BooksXml
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBookItems()
{
    List<BookItem> BookItems = new List<BookItem>();
    XDocument doc = _db.GetXmlDb();
    List<BookItem> bookitems = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookItem()
    {
        Id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
        Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
        Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
        Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
        Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
        Publish_date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
        Description = (string)x.Element("description")
    }).ToList();
    return Ok(bookitems);
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a Book item matching the given id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Id of item to be retrieved</param>
/// <returns>Book item</returns>
// GET: api/BooksXml/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetBookItems(string id)
{
    XDocument doc = _db.GetXmlDb();
    XElement result = doc.Descendants("book").FirstOrDefault(el => el.Attribute("id") != null &&
                 el.Attribute("id").Value == id);
    List<BookItem> BookItems = new List<BookItem>();
    if (result != null)
    {
        BookItem Book = new BookItem();
        Book.Id = (string)result.Attribute("id");
        Book.Author = (string)result.Element("author");
        Book.Title = (string)result.Element("title");
        Book.Genre = (string)result.Element("genre");
        Book.Price = (decimal)result.Element("price");
        Book.Publish_date = (DateTime)result.Element("publish_date");
        Book.Description = (string)result.Element("description");
        BookItems.Add(Book);

    }
    return Ok(BookItems);
}

[HttpGet("{title}")]
public IActionResult GetBookItemsByTitle(string title)
{
    // some code
    return Ok(bookitems);
}
```

I call this GetBookItemsByTitle(string title), and I even decorate it with or without the "title" like - [HttpGet("{title}")].

I read in log :

> Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET localhost:44378/api/BooksXml?title=aaaaa
>   Route matched with {action = "GetBookItems", controller = "BooksXml",
>   page = ""}.

but obviously it goes to wrong method.

In Angular client App the service corresponding three methods are

```
 /** GET all books from server. */
  getBookItems(): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(this.BookItemsUrl);
  }

  /** GET book by id. */
  getBookItem(id: string): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(url);
  }

  /** GET book by title from server. */
  getBookByTitle(title: string): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}?title=${title}`;
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(url);
  }
```

Whats wrong with my getBookByTitle Crud call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular in getBookByTitle url  is wrong see your getBookItem function. url    should  be  like  as follows.

```
getBookByTitle(title: string): Observable<BookItem[]> {
    const url = `${this.BookItemsUrl}/title/${title}`;
    return this.http.get<BookItem[]>(url);
  }
```

Change the  Api

```
[HttpGet("title/{title}")]
public IActionResult GetBookItemsByTitle(string title)
{
    // some code
    return Ok(bookitems);
}
```

Comment: When testing your code I get: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

WorkSampleBookSearch.BooksXmlController.GetBookItems (BooksProject)
WorkSampleBookSearch.BooksXmlController.GetBookItemsByTitle (BooksProject.
But I put [HttpGet("{title}")] on the method like you see in my code, any ide?

Comment: Router unable to understand  the difference between HTTPGET {title} and {id} change  the  route.I have  also edited the  code please try edited code. Hope it  will work.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your `[HttpGet("{title}")]` into `[HttpGet]` and it should work.

If you specify `{something}` in the constructor of `HttpGetAttribute` that means the parameter is given as part of the URL and not by the query string.